# Escalar una imagen en wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

estoy intentando hacer un tablero con un gripsizer en wx.python cuyas piezas del tablero son imágenes.

El problema es que el tamaño del tablero es variable y dependiendo del tamaño del tablero las imágenes tendrán que ocupar más o menos espacio

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de hacer que las imágenes(staticbitmap) se escalen automáticamente dependiendo del espacio que tengan

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola , ¿cómo organizas las imágenes exactamente? ¿GridSizer?

Comment: Si , tengo un panel de un cierto tamaño donde hay una tabla (de dimensiones cuadradas) del tamaño que diga el usuario, por ejemplo si tamaño=4  pues la tabla es de 4x4 y se crea una tabla que ocupa todo el espacio del panel con 16 casillas proporcionales.En cada casilla hay un staticbitmap(que tiene un tamaño) pero claro el tamaño de la casilla donde se coloca no es el mismo si es un 4x4 que si es un 9x9 , por eso lo que quiero saber es si en wx.python existe alguna forma de hacer que la imagen ocupe siempre el tamaño de la casilla , es decir que dependiendo del tamaño se vaya escalando